# Iphone SDK set static IP

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, static, ip

Does anyone know how to setup an IP address in iOs programmatically? It is really easy to do manually, just go to settings and configure the network. However, I want to do this inside a program, to connect to a WiFi network that do not have a DHCP server. Any pointers would help.

Update: This does not seem to be possible. Any suggestion on what I should do instead? The app needs to connect to a network that does not have a DHCP server.

Comment: Even on a desktop top system, I would still use the operating system control panel to set the static ip address.  An App wouldn't know what WiFi I am connected to to know what static ip address I would need.

Comment: This is wrong. You can both set the IP and acquire the bssid and ssid in most desktop OS's. Setting a static IP and getting the ssid is available in Android SDK, and there is a zillion apps on Android Market that do this. Some of them mine. Too bad this can't be done in iOs.

Comment: @Andy That must be fun when you get a rogue app. :-) Then again, it's very much the difference between the Android and iOS mindset. I'm not sure how it's relevant to this question, that said.

Comment: @middapark. You are right two times. This is not relevant as the app Im writing is for iOs, and Android and iOs are two different beasts. Still, there are use cases where this is neccesary, and not every network relies on DHCP. Some networks rely on preassigned IPs with strict MAC filtering, and my app is to be used in this context.

Comment: @Andy Ah.. didn't realise you were the OP. Guess you'll just have to use the OS level settings for iOS devices, painful though that may be. (Unless of course this isn't destined for the app store, in which case you might want to start nosing around header files.)

Comment: @Andy, if I am on a network that doesn't use DHCP, how would the app knows what static ip address to use?

Comment: Can not see how this question is poorly described, hence I do not understand why its downvoted.

Comment: Anyone know a way to do this with private API’s please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much suspect this isn't possible without the use of private APIs, as otherwise it would be possible for a malicious app to effectively "break" the user's network settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it within the Apple guidelines. It's probably a private API call. If you're talking about an app for jailbroken stuff, it might be a different store.